# inner join 3 tables in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables: orders, stocks, status

[image]

Final result:

> orders >> order_date = 2023-10-01 to 2023-10-30

> status >> status_id = 2,3,5

> stocks >> keyuser, stock_loc

Query:

```
select 
    s.keyuser, o.order_date 
from 
    stocks s
inner join 
    orders o on o.order_stock_id = s.stocks_id
inner join 
    status sta on sta.status_id = o.order_status_id
where 
    o.order_date <= date '2023-10-01'
    and o.order_date >= date '2023-10-30'
    and s.keyuser = 'kiki'
    and sta.status_id in (2, 3, 5)
```

Result: no output

Comment: i want to join this 3 tables and get order_date, ;keyuser, stock_loc value where the condition is describe in 'final result'.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your attempt, and then explain which part you are stuck on.

Comment: select s.keyuser, o.order_date from stocks s
inner join orders o on o.order_stock_id=s.stocks_id
inner join status sta on sta.status_id = o.order_status_id
where o.order_date <= date '2023-10-01'
and o.order_date >= date '2023-10-30'
and s.keyuser='kiki'
and sta.status_id in (2,3,5)

Comment: Your attempts looks good but since oracle is case sensitive DB, pls change `keyuser='KIKI'` and also be careful about date filters.

Comment: still not working

Comment: The date conditions should be the opposite.

Comment: Don't forget that dates in Oracle have a time portion, so if you're wanting to receive orders made on 2023-10-30 after midnight (e.g. 2023-10-30 14:36:29), you'd need to add a day and make the comparison a less-than, e.g. `and o.order_date < date '2023-10-31'`

Answer (score 2):

Your date range comparisons are the wrong way round and `KIKI` should be in upper-case to match your data:

```sql
select s.keyuser,
       o.order_date 
from   stocks s
       inner join orders o
       on o.order_stock_id = s.stocks_id
       inner join status sta
       on sta.status_id = o.order_status_id
where  o.order_date >= date '2023-10-01'
and    o.order_date <  date '2023-10-31'
and    s.keyuser = 'KIKI'
and    sta.status_id in (2, 3, 5)
```

*Note: In Oracle a `DATE` always has a time component; many client applications (i.e. SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, etc.) use a default format for `DATE`s that does not show the time component but it is still there even if it is not displayed. Therefore, if your time component of `order_date` is anything other than midnight you want to use `< DATE '2023-10-31'` rather than `<= DATE '2023-10-30'` so that you get a full 24 hour range on the final day.*

Answer (score 1):

```
select order_date, keyuser, stock_loc 
from orders as o
inner join status as s ON o.order_status_id = s.status_id
inner join stocks as sk ON o.order_stock_id = sk.stocks_id
where order_date >= DATE '2023-10-01' and order_date <= DATE '2023-10-30'
and status_id in (2,3,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date comparison is incorrect if you don't expect the recorded date to be both less than '2023-10-01' and greater than '2023-10-31'. Also, if you want it to work as case insensitive for your keyuser comparison, you need to specify it separately.

```
    select 
    s.keyuser, o.order_date 
from 
    stocks s
inner join 
    orders o on o.order_stock_id = s.stocks_id
inner join 
    status sta on sta.status_id = o.order_status_id
where 
    o.order_date >= date '2023-10-01'
    and o.order_date <= date '2023-10-30'
    and s.keyuser = 'kiki' collate binary_ci
    and sta.status_id in (2, 3, 5)
```